# Project not running after reinstalation of windows and Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I upgraded windows 10 to enterprise edition and also had to reinstall VS 2013 Express for Web.

After reinstalling i tried to run my project that used to run before but with no success.

It's trowing the following error:

Não foi possível carregar o ficheiro ou assemblagem 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou uma das respectivas dependências. A definição do manifesto de assemblagem localizada não corresponde à referência de assemblagem. (Excepção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Detalhes da Exceção: System.IO.FileLoadException: Não foi possível carregar o ficheiro ou assemblagem 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou uma das respectivas dependências. A definição do manifesto de assemblagem localizada não corresponde à referência de assemblagem. (Excepção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

What can be causing this? I've googled it but can't find any answer that solves my issue. Going crazy in here.

Thanks for your help guys. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you maybe post an english version of the error msg?

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The definition of the localized assembly manifest does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The definition of the localized assembly manifest does not match the assembly reference.